# How is oil-filled switchgear possible?

Tags: switches, high-voltage

I can't find any definitive description of how oil-filled switchgear uses the oil and manages to keep it from ignition and boiling. For example, [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Switchgear&oldid=501684170) says

> Oil circuit breakers rely upon vaporization of some of the oil to blast a jet of oil through the arc.

which sounds rather strange. The arc will be very hot, so oil moving anywhere near the arc would likely be ignited or start boiling and neither is good for any equipment.

How is oil used in oil-filled switchgear without igniting and boiling?

Comment: Actually there are oil types that are extremely difficult to use. For example there's what we call "mazut" here, I think that the correct translational is fuel-oil. You literally have to blast jets of flame onto it to heat it up for quite some time before it will ignite.

Comment: THe amount of energy absorption on a transmission line is a key part of selection of a switchgear.  (GigaJoules) Just as it is in MOV's However Lightning diversion designs must be included to protect transformers and switchgear from failure. This is a crutial part of transmission line protection. The flashpoint and quenching of flames from surrounding coolant must have been carefully designed to handle only certain loads while surges in some lightning may exceed that of transmission lines and cause failure.

Comment: If you generate a pocket of oil vapor in an oil bath, it can never burn, as there is no oxygen there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things you seem confused about.

First, if you have a arc that generates a pocket of oil-vapor that is submerged in a pool of liquid oil, it can *never* ignite, as **there is no oxygen there**.

With regard to quenching, basically the idea is to "stretch" the path of the arc until it breaks, and is as such quenched. There are actually high-power circuit breakers that specifically force a jet of air through the arc path when they open to quench the arc as rapidly as possible.

Basically, the liquid is *supposed* to boil, as this provides a source of gas. Also, it's worth remembering that the phase-change from liquid to gas requires a lot of energy, and this helps absorb the heat generated from the arc.

It is true that if a oil-immersed breaker cycles often, it will use up most of the oil, both through vaporization and carbonization, but the device should have sufficient oil to last for it's rated cycle-life.

Comment: The first time I heard about using air brakes to shut off a circuit, I thought they were nuts.  But they were talking about "air breaks", the device that blasts air through the arc...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misled by the idea, "neither is good for any equipment".  Breaking a high-voltage arc is a very specific problem, and one that has to be solved, and so special gear is designed for the purpose.  If ignition and boiling has to happen, then the gear can be designed to tolerate it.  Note in particular, that boiling removes heat, thus cooling the object that causes it.

Comment: Solutions for high voltage arcing has been solved and PCB worked well. The question begs an answer in chemistry to explain why it worked even if PCB is obsolete other dielectrics that are non-flammable or with very high flash-points and high insulating  dielectric properties for Hipot and high surge suppression , energy absorption properties. Duty cycle on these switchgear is low. so dwell time and recycle time are tightly spec'd.. Contactors oil filled may be purchased with full specs. Need specs? PCB has been replaced with CLF6 in some areas.

Comment: So, then, the answer to his question is, "They use special oil that doesn't burn or boil".

Comment: Not quite. they need to burn the oil to create the gas jet to extinguish the plasma flame. But if the question were. WHAT are the options for switchgear dielectric , costs, environmental issues , maintenance costs and MSDS risks? etc etc.. It might get a better answer.

Comment: I seem to recall Switchgear can only be used to close contacts and not OPEN which may cause explosions from excess arc breaking in some oil filled units. In any case , I read this is banned in UK but still in use in USA on old units. I read that old rugged-looking but contaminated switchgear is at the biggest risk as outward appearances are deceptive.

Answer (score -3):

*added* I believe the quenching of flames is similar to the quenching of SCR's with sufficiently low current for a few uSec.  This is why they use explosives to put out Oil Rig fires. "  You remove the flame and drop its temp with surrounding high mass fluid while the burst of plasma is moved by the rapid gas velocity of oil.  Now with nitrogen rich air or other inert gas as an air knife, one can make Green Friendly switchgear, but at higher costs. However the S2F10 gaseous products must be re-absorbed or evacuated safely. Is this the tpye of answer you needed?

---

The air dielectric is replaced with the oil dielectric. Currently ( no pun intended ) they are trying eradicate carcinogenic PCB toxic oils used in switchgear and Contractors.

The oil dielectric reduces flashover, contact bound and absorbs heat as weel as high voltage insulation breakdown and thin lubrication without preventing metal conductor path loss.

On another level switching high voltage beams or e-beams use a gas insulator called  Chlorine HexaFluoride ? (CLF6) as an gas insulator. But if the gas arcs fro high voltage e-beam and contaminant it turns in Mustard Gas, even more toxic than toxic PCB's. Literature is scares on this for a reason as not to frighten the public.

Also for this reason circuit boards wit etched copper for last 40 years have been called PWB's and not [**PCB**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polychlorinated_biphenyl) except those who are not sensitive or aware to the reasons why.

PCB oils used in Contractors and Transformers are toxic and DNA time bombs, and were early examples of bad chemistry used as chemotherapy. But it makes cheap insulator oil and improves with fast flow control of oil during transition break.

- - - - ADDED from WIKI

Oil-filled equipment allowed arc energy to be contained and safely controlled. By the early 20th century, a switchgear line-up would be a metal-enclosed structure with electrically operated switching elements, using oil circuit breakers. Today, oil-filled equipment has largely been replaced by air-blast, vacuum, or SF6 equipment, allowing large currents and power levels to be safely controlled by automatic equipment incorporating digital controls, protection, metering and communications.

Comment: writing many many extensions to your answers in comments is not how SE works, if you have more to add put it in your answer.